# jBCrypt fails to verify password

Tags: java, android, security, passwords, bcrypt

I'm working on encrypting passwords for my application since the password will be stored in the shared preferences

I found bcrypt and read a lot of good things about it but I can not get it to work

I'm using [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/). I followed the instructions and did this as a test

```
String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw("dog", BCrypt.gensalt(12));
String candidate = BCrypt.hashpw("dog", BCrypt.gensalt(12));
if (BCrypt.checkpw(candidate, hashed)){
    Toast.makeText(Loader.this, "equals", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(Loader.this, "don't match?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

However everytime i run the application the toast that displays is don't match? So when I log the hashed password in my shared prefs and then compare it against the user input it says it would say wrong everytime since apparently it's giving me a different hash everytime what's up how can i use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mindrot.org/files/jBCrypt/jBCrypt-0.2-doc/), `BCrypt.checkpw()` takes the **plaintext** password as its first argument. So it should be:

```
String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw("dog", BCrypt.gensalt(12));
String candidate = "dog";

if (BCrypt.checkpw(candidate, hashed)) {
    Toast.makeText(Loader.this, "equals", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(Loader.this, "doesn't match?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot :) sorry bout that thanks for the answer ha